# Frequent, odd freezes

Tags: freeze

For the past month I've been experiencing increasingly frequent freezes. It's gotten to the point where it will happen multiple times daily.

When a freeze occurs, the first sign is that my audio cuts out. Soon after, any video I'm watching will begin to buffer, and all windows open on my computer become unresponsive. My peripherals never stop working. I can close programs through task manager, but I cannot open new programs. If I try to restart or shut down my computer, it will be stuck buffering indefinitely. The only way to solve the issue is to manually shut off my pc.

These freezes give no crash report, no minidump files, nothing appears in event viewer, but I'm not sure what hardware could be causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a Windows minidump file in C:\Windows\Minidump

Get Nirsoft Blue Screen View. Use this to view the minidump.

Most likely there is a fatal hardware error. Blue Screen View can help identify the component. Video and memory are likely candidates.  Main CPU less so in my experience.

===========

You may need to turn Mini Dumps ON.

Click System and Security from within the Control Panel:

Then click System from the list:

Now, click Advanced System Settings:

Under the Start-up and Recovery section, click Settings:

Finally, select Small Memory Dump from the debugging drop-down menu, then click OK:

Comment: The OP states "These freezes give no crash report, **no minidump files**"

Comment: I added a section to turn on Mini Dumps. They can be created without a visible crash report. However, how to make them is a worthwhile procedure.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've already installed and tried to use Nirsoft Blue Screen View, but the setting for minidump files was set to automatic instead of small. Not sure if this could have made any difference, but I've changed it and will check again after the next freeze. Video causing the problem does make a lot of sense, as I can't recall a crash occurring without watching youtube at the time, I will have to experiment with this further.

Comment: Thanks,  Don't forget to go to Blue Screen View, Advanced Options, and browse for your mini dump file.